# Parsing SQL Queries by semicolon

Tags: sql, regex, scala, parsing

I'm trying to read, using Scala, a sql file full of queries to be executed, however, I'm struggling to parse special cases that contain a semicolon that is not the terminator. For example, if the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%;%",
```

It separates this into two statements even though it should be one.

Comment: I don't think we can give you any help without seeing your Scala/Java code, and also a larger example of SQL code.  Can you tell us all the cases in which a semicolon does _not_ mark the end of a statement?

Comment: is it safe to assume that where semicolon is a terminator, it would be the last character in that line?

Comment: It is hard to build regular expressions for every case. You should use a sql parser to get complete sqls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the query terminator is always a `;` at the end of a line, we can make good use of

- `.split(";\\s*\\n");` matching the `;` zero or more whitespace characters follows by an newline character.
- or `.split("(?m);\\s*$")` using the inline `(?m)` multiline modifier that allows us to match the end of the line with `$`).

Sample Code:

```
 val a = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%;%"
    AND regexp_replace(
      'abcd1234df-TEXT_I-WANT'  -- use your input column here instead
    , '^[a-z0-9]{10}-(.*)\$'     -- matches whole string, captures "TEXT_I-WANT" in \$1
    , '\$1'                      -- inserts \$1 to returnÖ TEXT_I-WANT
    ) = 'TEXT_I-WANT'
;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%;%"
    AND regexp_replace(
      'abcd1234df-TEXT_I-WANT'  -- use your input column here instead
    , '^[a-z0-9]{10}-(.*)\$'     -- matches whole string, captures "TEXT_I-WANT" in \$1
    , '\$1'                      -- inserts \$1 to returnÖ TEXT_I-WANT
    ) = 'TEXT_I-WANT'
    ;""".split(";\\s*\\n")
println(a.mkString("Next Query:"))
```

- If you prefer to match, this pattern can do a good job too: `"(?m)^[\\s\\S]*?;$"`
  (add additional whitespace `\s` as needed)

Full Sample:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val pattern = new Regex("(?m)^[\\s\\S]*?;\\s*$")
      val str = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%;%"
    AND regexp_replace(
      'abcd1234df-TEXT_I-WANT'  -- use your input column here instead
    , '^[a-z0-9]{10}-(.*)\$'     -- matches whole string, captures "TEXT_I-WANT" in \$1
    , '\$1'                      -- inserts \$1 to returnÖ TEXT_I-WANT
    ) = 'TEXT_I-WANT'
   ;        
   SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%;%"
    AND regexp_replace(
      'abcd1234df-TEXT_I-WANT'  -- use your input column here instead
    , '^[a-z0-9]{10}-(.*)\$'     -- matches whole string, captures "TEXT_I-WANT" in \$1
    , '\$1'                      -- inserts \$1 to returnÖ TEXT_I-WANT
    ) = 'TEXT_I-WANT'
    ;"""

      println((pattern findAllIn str).mkString("\n----------------\n"))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `^.*?;$` with m option (to match new line) as mentioned [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_regular_expressions.htm)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lpuuNi/1)